# Criar um select de cidades, quando escolher a cidade vai para o site especifico da cidade escolhida

Tags: php, html, jquery

Esse é meu select, a muito tempo tento usar mais não sei como funciona, vejo que muitos sites grandes usam e ao usuário selecionar a cidade ele mostra o conteúdo respectivo, porém a URL não muda.

```
<form action="cid.php" method="get">
    <select name="cidade" id="cidade">
        <option>Selecione</option>
        <option value="Cidade 1">Cidade 1</option>
        <option value="Cidade 2">Cidade 2</option>
        <option value="Cidade 3">Cidade 3</option>
    </select>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="botao" value="Ok">
</form>
```

Quem puder ajudar ou me dar uma direção agradeço muito.

Comment: Tem certeza que a URL não muda? Ao pressionar o botão *Ok* a URL deveria ser algo como `cid.php?cidade=Cidade%201`. Alguns navegadores atuais omitem a *query string* da URL por padrão, então já tentou recuperar o valor no PHP com `$_GET`?

Comment: Ele mostra "cidade=Cidade+1&submit=Ok", queria saber como faço para ele pegar a página da determinada cidade.

Comment: E que página seria essa?

Comment: O site é de telecom, cada cidade tem um valor, ai seria tipo: cidade 1 = página 1.    Como é feito nesse site e em muitos outros: http://www.evonetworks.com.br/cid.php | https://www.brisanet.com.br

Comment: Como eu faria para que a escolha do usuário se mantenha mesmo que ele mude de página? Digamos que o usuário acessou o site e escolheu sua cidade, mas depois de trocar de página no mesmo site, a escolha se mantenha. Eu fiz como acima citado e deu certo, porém, quando o usuário navega pra outras páginas, isso se perde.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode colocar o HTML assim:

```
<form action="cid.php" method="get">
    <select name="cidade" id="cidade">
        <option>Selecione</option>
        <option value="city1">Cidade 1</option>
        <option value="city2">Cidade 2</option>
        <option value="city3">Cidade 3</option>
    </select>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="botao" value="Ok">
</form>
```

E no código do arquivo `cid.php`, você pode fazer uma lógica mais ou menos assim:

```
<?php

    switch ($_GET['citade']) {
        case 'city1':
            header('Location: /cidade-1.php');
            exit;

        case 'city3':
            header('Location: /cidade-1.php');
            exit;

        case 'city3':
            header('Location: /cidade-1.php');
            exit;

        default:
            header('Location: /default.php');
            exit;
    }
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, agora acho que é só usar ajax para a URL se manter a mesma para não ficar: www.meusite.com.br/cidade-1

Comment: Existe alguma maneira de fazer o GET junto com meu ajax de refresh?

Comment: Se você quiser deixar a URL fixa sem usar ajax, pode usar <?php include('cidade-1.php');?>